# Bizarre behavior when modifying List(of Object): duplicating last item

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

When iterating over a text file as I do very frequently without issue the *List(Of Franchise)* is adding the last line in the the text file 12 times to my list rather than adding 12 unique items.  Has anyone every experienced this before?  I will use Linq and Lambda Expressions heavily later on once the Object is fully defined.

I tested my code to make sure I'm not crazy by populating Lists of Strings and verifying I am getting 12 unique values.  It has something to do with my Object definition.

**League Object**

```
Public Class League
    Public Property Owners As List(Of Francise)

    Public Sub New()
        Owners = New List(Of Francise)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Franchise Object**

```
Public Class Francise

Public Shared Property ownerName As String = ""
Public Shared Property ownerID As String = ""   
Public Shared Property rosteredPlayers As List(Of Player)
Public Shared Property startedPlayers As List(Of Player)    
Public Shared Property benchedPlayers As List(Of Player)
Public Shared Property starterPoints As Decimal = 0
Public Shared Property benchPoints As Decimal = 0       

Public Sub New()
    rosteredPlayers = New List(Of Player)
    startedPlayers = New List(Of Player)
    benchedPlayers = New List(Of Player)
End Sub

End Class
```

**Player Object**

```
Public Class Player
    Public Property name As String = ""

    Public Property year As String = ""
    Public Property week As String = ""

    Public Property FantraxID As String = ""
    Public Property StatsIncID As String = ""
    Public Property sportradarId As String = ""
    Public Property rotowireId As String = ""
    Public Property team As String = ""
    Public Property position As String = ""

    Public Property status As String = ""
End Class
```

**Class where I am accessing and populating the League object**

```
        ' Create League Object
        thisLeague = New League() ' <- previously undefined Shared object in another class

        '*******read through settings and add the teams*******'
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dir & "\LeagueSettings.txt")
            currentLine = sr.ReadLine
            Do While (Not currentLine Is Nothing)

                If currentLine.Contains("id:") Then 
                    Dim f As Francise = New Francise

                    'name
                    f.ownerName = currentLine.Split(","c)(1).Split(":"c)(1)
                    ' ID
                    f.ownerID = currentLine.Split(","c)(2).Split(":"c)(1)

                    thisLeague.Owners.Add(f)
                End If

                currentLine = sr.ReadLine
            Loop
        End Using
```

**Iterating over Text File**

```
dailpcnij67b2yqn,name:Marlon Bermudez (@Marlonb_21),id:dailpcnij67b2yqn
1bk8tc3gj67b2zew,name:Bob Lung (@bob_lung),id:1bk8tc3gj67b2zew
qqzscc6jj67b2ymc,name:Josh (@FantasyADHD),id:qqzscc6jj67b2ymc
730u1741j67b2yl1,name:Patrick Bergman (@Phrankie_D),id:730u1741j67b2yl1
gidjhqi0j67b2za8,name:John Di Bari (@dibari22),id:gidjhqi0j67b2za8
57u5kpdjj67b2z5s,name:Kyle Shumway (@ffpadawan),id:57u5kpdjj67b2z5s
ie2nod6wj67b2yoh,name:LAJJ (@lajjjj),id:ie2nod6wj67b2yoh
7nbcgudyj67b2zj9,name:Rob Waziak (@WazNFL),id:7nbcgudyj67b2zj9
cxshguvxj67b40ca,name:Tim Wagner (@X_fan12),id:cxshguvxj67b40ca
jkxb910ij67b2ytk,name:Kenneth Cashman (@RotoWear),id:jkxb910ij67b2ytk
n33hlz39j67b2z16,name:Matt Harmon (@MattHarmon_BYB),id:n33hlz39j67b2z16
7h6ivrntj67b2yx4,name:Thor (@Thoreosnmilk),id:7h6ivrntj67b2yx4
```

Comment: Do you know what [`Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) does?  You could save yourself a lot of grief by serializing your collection(s) rather than reading and parsing a  text file.  Rather than 3 versions of the Player list, if player had a `Status` property and you could use linq (not sure why you have that tag for the post as is) to get whichever subset you need from the master list.

Comment: This is not related to your questions, but I want to point out that you can always write `Dim sth as New Something` instead of `Dim sth as Something = New Something`. Also, use [`IsNot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/isnot-operator) instead of `Not .. Is`.

Comment: None of the properties in the Franchise class should be Shared.

Comment: @Plutonix 1. You solved it!  When I was reusing old code Public Property turned into Public Shared Property.
2. I am in the process of bringing in information from a client into one of my projects.  When I am done yes I will be serializing everything.
3. Also good point on the 3 lists.  I will resolve those into 1 list and use status.

Comment: @HansPassant You are correct.  THis fixed the issue.  It was a typo from too much copy-pasta on an old project.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I just recently realized you could do this, but its a tough habit to break.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Plutonix @HansPassant
I got a little overzealous with my *Shared* Blocks when I was copy and pasting old code.  None of the properties should have been shared.

**Corrected Franchise Class**

```
Public Class Francise

Public Property ownerName As String = ""
Public Property ownerID As String = ""   
Public Property rosteredPlayers As List(Of Player)
Public Property startedPlayers As List(Of Player)    
Public Property benchedPlayers As List(Of Player)
Public Property starterPoints As Decimal = 0
Public Property benchPoints As Decimal = 0       

Public Sub New()
    rosteredPlayers = New List(Of Player)
    startedPlayers = New List(Of Player)
    benchedPlayers = New List(Of Player)
End Sub

End Class
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold I marked it as the answer and provided a bit of documentation.  Stackoverflow is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming other part of the code has null check (file not exist, ex.) and all variables are properly defined previously. Try do the while loop like this -

```
       Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dir & "\LeagueSettings.txt")

        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
            currentLine = sr.ReadLine
            If currentLine.Contains("id:") Then 
                Dim f As Francise = New Francise

                'name
                f.ownerName = currentLine.Split(","c)(1).Split(":"c)(1)
                ' ID
                f.ownerID = currentLine.Split(","c)(2).Split(":"c)(1)

                thisLeague.Owners.Add(f)
            End If
        Loop
```